# Package microtype Warning: I cannot find a spacing list for font (microtype)

Tags: spacing, microtype

I am getting that warning message here when using the package nicematrix in Texmaker on an Ubuntu-PC. I have never seen that before in any setting:

```
Package microtype Warning: I cannot find a spacing list for font
(microtype) `TS1/lmr/m/n/12'.
```

Is there the chance that I can get rid of that by for example changing settings or installing a package in some way?

A minimal working example is that one here:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    pagesize,
    pdftex,
    12pt,
    twoside, % + BCOR darunter: für doppelseitigen Druck aktivieren, sonst beide deaktivieren
    BCOR=5mm, % Dicke der Bindung berücksichtigen (Copyshop fragen, wie viel das ist)
    ngerman,
    fleqn,
    final,
    pdftex,dvipsnames,%manuel ergaenzt
    ]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{ucs} entfernt, machte Ärger
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Eingabekodierung: UTF-8
%\usepackage{fixltx2e} % Schickere Ausgabe, nicht mehr nötig
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ordentliche Trennung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern} % ordentliche Schriften
\usepackage{setspace,graphicx,tikz,tabularx} % für Elemente der Titelseite
\usepackage[draft=false,babel,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true]{microtype} % optischer Randausgleich etc.
% Eigene Paketimporte
\usepackage{tikz}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{scrhack} % getting rid of floating error message with listings

% Package und Befehle für ToDo-Notes
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage{multicol}


\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000
\vbadness=10001

\begin{document}

\subsection{Appendix}
\vfill\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\resizebox{14cm}{!}{ 
\label{tab:1}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccllll}%
 [ 
   vlines ,
   code-before = 
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{4-2}{5-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{6-2}{7-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{8-2}{9-6}
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{10-2}{11-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{12-2}{13-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{14-2}{15-6}
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{16-2}{17-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{18-2}{19-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{20-2}{21-6}
 ]
\Hline
\Block{3-1}{Modell} & \Block{3-1}{Batch} & \Block[c]{1-4}{Lernrate} \\ \Hline
                     &                           & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.05}    & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.10}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.15}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.20}   \\ \Hline
                     &                           & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}    & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}   \\ \Hline
\Block{6-1}{M-Flair}& \Block{2-1}{16}        & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,0.60      \,\,\,\,\,0.71     & \,\,\,\,0.87       \,\,\,\,\,0.69      \,\,\,\,\,0.77     & \,\,\,\,0.87       \,\,\,\,\,0.74      \,\,\,\,\,0.80     & \,\,\,\,0.87       \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.79}     \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.83}    \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.04       ±0.03      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.02       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{32}        & \,\,\,\,0.88       \,\,\,\,\,0.49      \,\,\,\,\,0.63     & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,0.59      \,\,\,\,\,0.70     & \,\,\,\,0.88       \,\,\,\,\,0.66      \,\,\,\,\,0.75     & \,\,\,\,0.87       \,\,\,\,\,0.69      \,\,\,\,\,0.77     \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.02       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.02       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.02       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{64}        & \,\,\,\,0.88       \,\,\,\,\,0.46      \,\,\,\,\,0.60     & \,\,\,\,0.87       \,\,\,\,\,0.54      \,\,\,\,\,0.66     & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,0.56      \,\,\,\,\,0.68     & \,\,\,\,\textbf{0.88}      \,\,\,\,\,0.61      \,\,\,\,\,0.72     \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
\Block{6-1}{BERT}& \Block{2-1}{16}       & \,\,\,\,0.85       \,\,\,\,\,0.78      \,\,\,\,\,0.82     & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,0.80      \,\,\,\,\,0.83     & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,0.81      \,\,\,\,\,0.83     & \,\,\,\,0.87       \,\,\,\,\,0.80      \,\,\,\,\,0.83     \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{32}        & \,\,\,\,0.84       \,\,\,\,\,0.74      \,\,\,\,\,0.79     & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,0.78      \,\,\,\,\,0.82     & \,\,\,\,\textit{0.87}      \,\,\,\,\,0.80      \,\,\,\,\,\textbf{0.83}    & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,\textbf{0.81}     \,\,\,\,\,0.83     \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{64}        & \,\,\,\,0.83       \,\,\,\,\,0.68      \,\,\,\,\,0.75     & \,\,\,\,0.85       \,\,\,\,\,0.75      \,\,\,\,\,0.80     & \,\,\,\,0.85       \,\,\,\,\,0.76      \,\,\,\,\,0.80     & \,\,\,\,0.86       \,\,\,\,\,0.78      \,\,\,\,\,0.82     \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
\Block{6-1}{XLM-R}& \Block{2-1}{16}      & \,\,\,\,0.78       \,\,\,\,\,0.49      \,\,\,\,\,0.60     & \,\,\,\,0.77       \,\,\,\,\,0.51      \,\,\,\,\,0.61     & \,\,\,\,0.79       \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.52}     \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.63}    & \,\,\,\,\textit{0.79}      \,\,\,\,\,0.50      \,\,\,\,\,0.61     \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.02       ±0.02      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{32}        & \,\,\,\,0.77       \,\,\,\,\,0.48      \,\,\,\,\,0.59     & \,\,\,\,0.77       \,\,\,\,\,0.49      \,\,\,\,\,0.60     & \,\,\,\,0.78       \,\,\,\,\,0.51      \,\,\,\,\,0.62     & \,\,\,\,0.78       \,\,\,\,\,0.50      \,\,\,\,\,0.61     \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.02       ±0.02      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{64}        & \,\,\,\,0.76       \,\,\,\,\,0.44      \,\,\,\,\,0.56     & \,\,\,\,0.78       \,\,\,\,\,0.48      \,\,\,\,\,0.60     & \,\,\,\,0.77       \,\,\,\,\,0.49      \,\,\,\,\,0.60     & \,\,\,\,0.78       \,\,\,\,\,0.50      \,\,\,\,\,0.61     \\             
                &                        & ±0.03      ±0.01       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
\end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{table}
\vfill%\newpage

\vfill\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Table 2}
\resizebox{14cm}{!}{ 
\label{tab:2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccllll}%
 [ 
   vlines ,
   code-before = 
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{4-2}{5-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{6-2}{7-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{8-2}{9-6}
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{10-2}{11-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{12-2}{13-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{14-2}{15-6}
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{16-2}{17-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{18-2}{19-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{20-2}{21-6}
 ]
\Hline
\Block{3-1}{Modell} & \Block{3-1}{Batch} & \Block[c]{1-4}{Lernrate} \\ \Hline
                     &                           & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.05}    & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.10}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.15}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{0.20}   \\ \Hline
                     &                           & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}    & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}   & \Block[c]{1-1}{Pre\,\,\,\,\, Rec\,\,\,\,\, F1}   \\ \Hline
\Block{6-1}{M-Flair}& \Block{2-1}{16}        & \,\,\,\,0.64       \,\,\,\,\,0.42      \,\,\,\,\,0.51     & \,\,\,\,0.67       \,\,\,\,\,0.50      \,\,\,\,\,0.57     & \,\,\,\,\textit{0.68}      \,\,\,\,\,0.55      \,\,\,\,\,0.60     & \,\,\,\,0.67       \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.58}     \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.62}    \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.02       ±0.02      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{32}        & \,\,\,\,0.57       \,\,\,\,\,0.32      \,\,\,\,\,0.41     & \,\,\,\,0.63       \,\,\,\,\,0.43      \,\,\,\,\,0.51     & \,\,\,\,0.66       \,\,\,\,\,0.48      \,\,\,\,\,0.55     & \,\,\,\,0.66       \,\,\,\,\,0.50      \,\,\,\,\,0.56     \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.02       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{64}        & \,\,\,\,0.54       \,\,\,\,\,0.29      \,\,\,\,\,0.38     & \,\,\,\,0.62       \,\,\,\,\,0.38      \,\,\,\,\,0.47     & \,\,\,\,0.63       \,\,\,\,\,0.39      \,\,\,\,\,0.48     & \,\,\,\,0.64       \,\,\,\,\,0.44      \,\,\,\,\,0.52     \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
\Block{6-1}{BERT}& \Block{2-1}{16}       & \,\,\,\,0.72       \,\,\,\,\,0.66      \,\,\,\,\,0.69     & \,\,\,\,0.73       \,\,\,\,\,0.68      \,\,\,\,\,0.70     & \,\,\,\,0.74       \,\,\,\,\,0.69      \,\,\,\,\,0.71     & \,\,\,\,\textit{0.75}      \,\,\,\,\,0.69      \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.72}    \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{32}        & \,\,\,\,0.71       \,\,\,\,\,0.63      \,\,\,\,\,0.67     & \,\,\,\,0.73       \,\,\,\,\,0.67      \,\,\,\,\,0.70     & \,\,\,\,0.74       \,\,\,\,\,0.68      \,\,\,\,\,0.71     & \,\,\,\,0.74       \,\,\,\,\,\textit{0.69}     \,\,\,\,\,0.72     \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{64}        & \,\,\,\,0.67       \,\,\,\,\,0.59      \,\,\,\,\,0.63     & \,\,\,\,0.70       \,\,\,\,\,0.64      \,\,\,\,\,0.67     & \,\,\,\,0.72       \,\,\,\,\,0.66      \,\,\,\,\,0.68     & \,\,\,\,0.72       \,\,\,\,\,0.66      \,\,\,\,\,0.69     \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
\Block{6-1}{XLM-R}& \Block{2-1}{16}      & \,\,\,\,0.75       \,\,\,\,\,0.73      \,\,\,\,\,0.74     & \,\,\,\,0.77       \,\,\,\,\,0.75      \,\,\,\,\,0.76     & \,\,\,\,\textbf{0.78}      \,\,\,\,\,\textbf{0.77}     \,\,\,\,\,\textbf{0.78}    & \,\,\,\,0.78       \,\,\,\,\,0.77      \,\,\,\,\,0.77     \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{32}        & \,\,\,\,0.73       \,\,\,\,\,0.71      \,\,\,\,\,0.72     & \,\,\,\,0.75       \,\,\,\,\,0.73      \,\,\,\,\,0.74     & \,\,\,\,0.76       \,\,\,\,\,0.75      \,\,\,\,\,0.75     & \,\,\,\,0.77       \,\,\,\,\,0.76      \,\,\,\,\,0.76     \\             
                &                        & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.02       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.00       ±0.00      \\ \Hline      
                & \Block{2-1}{64}        & \,\,\,\,0.72       \,\,\,\,\,0.68      \,\,\,\,\,0.70     & \,\,\,\,0.74       \,\,\,\,\,0.71      \,\,\,\,\,0.73     & \,\,\,\,0.75       \,\,\,\,\,0.73      \,\,\,\,\,0.74     & \,\,\,\,0.75       \,\,\,\,\,0.74      \,\,\,\,\,0.75     \\             
                &                        & ±0.01      ±0.00       ±0.00      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.01      ±0.01       ±0.01      & ±0.00      ±0.01       ±0.01      \\ \Hline      
\end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Sorry that the tables are so big.

Comment: I'm the author of `nicematrix`. An interaction between `microtype` and `nicematrix` seems very odd. You should provide a complet (non)-working example producing this error message.

Comment: I have added a minimum working example which gives me that message on my computer. Sorry that the tables are so big.

Comment: I have no problem compiling your document with `pdflatex`. You should update your TeX installation (MikTeX, TeXLive, MacTeX, etc.).

Comment: Funny, I was sure about that it what be something on my PC. Interestingly, I set up the PC a week ago, installing TeXlive 2020. So I am sure this has something to do with something not being installed?

Comment: You should try to found the problem by creating a more compact MWE. Try to load less packages...

Comment: You can add empty settings for `TS1` encoding: `\SetExtraSpacing{ encoding = {TS1} } { }`

Comment: This has been fixed in the current version (v2.8a).

Comment: I just updated and recompiled it and it works! Thank you for the fix

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately, I keep having the issue with `TS1/Libertinus-Serif-TLF/m/n/12` and `microtype` v2.8c.